# Retrieving column names from information schema as values for dbt snapshot

Tags: google-bigquery, snapshot, dbt

I have the following macro that returns the column names from a table excluding ones that I don't need

```
{%- macro get_column_names_excl_meta_cols(schema_name, table_name) -%}
    {% set table_query %}
        select 
            string_agg("'" || column_name || "'")
        from 
        {%- if target.name == 'prod' -%}
            gcp-project-prod.{{ schema_name }}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        {%- elif  target.name == 'test' -%}
            gcp-project-test.{{ schema_name }}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        {%- else -%}
            gcp-project-dev.{{ schema_name }}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        {%- endif -%}
        where table_name = '{{ table_name }}'
            and column_name not in ('meta_ingest_ts')
    {% endset %}

    {%- set result = run_query(table_query).columns[0].values()[0] -%}
    {{return( result )}}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

I want to use this in my snapshot model store_hist as follows -

```
{% snapshot store_hist %}
{{
    config(
        target_schema=generate_schema_name('stores'),
        strategy='check',
        invalidate_hard_deletes=True,
        unique_key='store_no',
        check_cols=get_column_names_excl_meta_cols('stores', 'store_master')
    )
}}
with base as (
    select
        *
    from {{ src_table('stores', 'store_master') }}
)
select *
from base

{% endsnapshot %}
```

when I run the command `dbt run snapshot` I am getting an error -

> Compilation Error in snapshot store_hist (snapshots\store_hist.sql)
> 'None' has no attribute 'table'

When I hard code all the column names of table in check_cols, it's working as expected. Can someone help me with this?

Also I am bit new to the macros. Looking at some examples of run_query, I see that this bit of code is present. Do I need to incorporate this as well? When I do keep this, the dbt snapshot command doesn't run at all, so I removed the if part of it.

```
{% if execute %}
    {%- set result = run_query(table_query).columns[0].values()[0] -%}
    {{return( result )}}
{% else %}
    {{return( false ) }}
{% endif %}
```

libraries I am using are --

dbt-core==1.5
dbt-bigquery==1.5

Implementing using dbt-cli

Comment: You’re returning a comma delimited string. You need to return an array to pass into check_cols. And, yes, you do need to check the execute boolean.

Comment: Thanks @AdamKipnis. I modified string_agg function to array_agg and added the execute boolean check. I am getting following error - Parsing Error  at path ['check_cols']: False is not valid under any of the given schemas. If I remove that 'if' clause, I am getting same error. Would you be able to explain what that condition flag does? I am running the dbt snapshot command.